# Change the theme at runtime

Tags: linux, gtk#

I have a GTK# 3 application under Linux and I would like to force a theme selected from the application rather than the system one.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**GTK# 3** can load a **CSS** theme at runtime and you can recursively apply it to all the children of a widget.

```
var cssProvider = new CssProvider();

cssProvider.LoadFromData(yourCssThemeAsString);

ApplyCssRecursively(window, cssProvider, UInt32.MaxValue);

static void ApplyCssRecursively(Widget widget, IStyleProvider provider, uint priority)
{
    widget.StyleContext.AddProvider(provider, priority);

    var container = widget as Container;

    if (container == null) return;

    foreach (var child in container.Children)
        ApplyCssRecursively(child, provider, priority);
}
```

Comment: Better to use `StyleContext.AddProviderForScreen` once, instead of `AddProvider` recursively on who knows how many widgets.